# UI Router doesn't load the expected child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Given the following configuration:

```
$stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html'
    })

    .state('app.player', {
      url: '/players/:playerId',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/player.html',
          controller: 'PlayerCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.player.lesson', {
      url: '/lessons/:lessonId',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/lesson.html',
          controller: 'LessonCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

When visiting `/app/players/2/lessons/8`, the `app.player` state is activated. Why not the `app.player.lesson` state? What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have any ui-view in player.html? Or can you share your player.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6brYIR9nPuDTvYPD1diw?p=preview), which shows, that we have to

1. either change the content of the `templateUrl: 'templates/player.html'` to contain `<div ui-view="menuContent"></div>` or
2. we have to use absolute view naming:  'menuContent@app'

a snippet

```
.state('app.player.lesson', {
    url: '/chapter/:lessonId',
    views: {
      'menuContent@app': {
        templateUrl: 'templates.lesson.tpl.html',
        controller: 'LessonCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Where was the issue? A child **player** was targeting the `ui-view` 'menuContent'. The grand child was targeting the `ui-view` with the same name - 'menuContent'.

But these names are converted into absolute path. And in this case, it means the view in a parent. With the help of `'@'` sign we can add our custom absolute path.

See: - [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

*NOTE in the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6brYIR9nPuDTvYPD1diw?p=preview) I am showing both, Lesson uses the parent ui-view, while chapter targets grand parent...*